# LNK2019 error, tries nearly everything, nothing works

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake, linker-errors, sfml

Sorry for my English, not my main language, hope everyone will understand.
I'm trying to make games for the first time, five years after my first line of code. Since I want to make something organised and easy to read, I decided to use CMake to create a Visual Studio project containing various libraries for different parts of my future code, and to link each libraries with the SFML where I need it.

Unfortunately, I'm not really good at CMake. So, what should have taken a little of my time took a loooot more. I've already overcome some difficulties, but right now, I'm very blocked. Everything I try don't resolve my problem so it's really annoying.

Well, the problem now! Every libraries that I create should have been linked to the SFML one. Except, they obviously don't. That the error I got when I compile my solution (they're in french, but I think you'll get the idea):

- core_data.lib(GameLoop.obj) : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "public: virtual __thiscall sf::Window::~Window(void)" (??1Window@sf@@UAE@XZ)
- core_data.lib(GameLoop.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: __thiscall sf::String::String(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::locale const &)" (??0String@sf@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?
- $char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABVlocale@3@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "private: void __thiscall GameLoop::initMainWindow(void)" (?initMainWindow@GameLoop@@AAEXXZ)
- core_data.lib(GameLoop.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: __thiscall sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0VideoMode@sf@@QAE@III@Z) référencé dans la fonction "private: void __thiscall GameLoop::initMainWindow(void)" (?initMainWindow@GameLoop@@AAEXXZ)
- core_data.lib(GameLoop.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: __thiscall sf::Window::Window(void)" (??0Window@sf@@QAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: __thiscall GameLoop::GameLoop(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0GameLoop@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
- core_data.lib(GameLoop.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: void __thiscall sf::Window::create(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (?create@Window@sf@@QAEXVVideoMode@2@ABVString@2@IABUContextSettings@2@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "private: void __thiscall GameLoop::initMainWindow(void)" (?initMainWindow@GameLoop@@AAEXXZ)
- core_data.lib(GameLoop.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::isOpen(void)const " (?isOpen@Window@sf@@QBE_NXZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: int __thiscall GameLoop::run(void)" (?run@GameLoop@@QAEHXZ)
- C:\Users\Fleurus\Desktop\build\sfmlBase\bin\Debug\sfmlBase.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 externes non résolus

Every call to a SFML function end up to a linkage error. If I'm not wrong, that's the sign of .lib that are not included. Except they seem to be included by what I did in the CMakeLists.txt. What's below is a macro that is called for every library created that use the SFML:

```
MACRO(Library_Configuration)

# We get the name of the current builded library with the name of the current directory
get_filename_component(LIB_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} NAME) 
# We set the complete name of the library
set(COMPLETE_LIBRARY_NAME  ${MOD_NAME}_${LIB_NAME})
# We define the path of the headers files
set(HEADER_FILES_PATH ../../../include/${MOD_NAME})
# Inclusion of headers files
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES ${HEADER_FILES_PATH}/${LIB_NAME}/*.h)
# If there is header files
if(EXISTS ${HEADER_FILES})
    set(LIBRARY_BUILT ON)
    # We take every source files of the current directory 
    file(GLOB SOURCES_FILES *.cpp)      
    # We build the library with headers and sources previously research
    add_library(${COMPLETE_LIBRARY_NAME} ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCES_FILES})
    # That's where seems to be the problem
    target_include_directories(${COMPLETE_LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC ${HEADER_FILES_PATH} ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/export) 
    target_link_libraries(${COMPLETE_LIBRARY_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
    set_property(TARGET ${COMPLETE_LIBRARY_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER ${MOD_NAME})

    # Fichier d'export... 
    generate_export_header(${COMPLETE_LIBRARY_NAME} EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/export/${COMPLETE_LIBRARY_NAME}_export.h)
    set (LIBRARY_BUILT_LIST )
    set (LIBRARY_BUILT_LIST ${LIBRARY_BUILT_LIST} ${COMPLETE_LIBRARY_NAME} CACHE INTERNAL "LIBRARY_BUILT_LIST")

else()
    set(LIBRARY_BUILT OFF) 
endif()
ENDMACRO()
```

For a better understanding, this is the architecture of my work directory:

- app (Where the entry point of my program is)
- include(Should be obvious)

  - core

    - physics
    - audio
    - data
    - controls
    - graphics
  - game

    - physics
    - audio
    - data
    - controls
    - graphics
- src

  - core

    - physics
    - audio
    - data
    - controls
    - graphics
  - game

    - physics
    - audio
    - data
    - controls
    - graphics
- CMakeLists.txt (the main one)

There it is. Hope I'm clear enough for you to help me. Thank you!

Edit : Thank you for the tag as duplicate, but the thread doesn't really help. I know what is the LNK2019 error, I don't  know how to resolve this error adding something in my Cmakelist macro...